# Axios post request not sent to external url: TypeError: ns.GetCommandSrc is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I got a react app sending some post, get etc requests to an external URL using axios (^0.19.2). The get requests are sent and received properly, though post requests trigger a JS error and are even not sent:

`TypeError: ns.GetCommandSrc is not a function`

Checking the reference brings me to this method:

```
function GetCommandUrl()
{
    var commandSrc = ns.GetCommandSrc() + "/to/ajaxRequestNotify";
    return (document.location.protocol === "https:") ? commandSrc.replace("http:", "https:") : commandSrc;
}
```

My code is actually pretty simple:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    const accessToken <my access token>;
    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://<remote url>/customer/check',
        data: {access_token : accessToken}
    })
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
    });
}
```

**-- UPDATE AFTER SOLVING THE ISSUE --**

This function is coming from Kaspersky javascript injection. Solved it by disabling Inject scripts into web traffic to interact with web pages

In `Kaspersky: Settings -> Additional -> Network -> Inject scripts into web traffic to interact with web pages`.

Comment: add your GetCommandSrc code as well

Comment: Found the answer myself. This function is not my function but coming from Kaspersky

Comment: Wait, Kaspersky injects javascript into your webpages? Does it also do this for webpages that are encrypted?